# OAuth2.0 response_type and grant_type

Tags: authentication, server, oauth-2.0, authorization

I'm trying to build an Oauth2.0 Authorization server and I wanted to understand more about the response_type and grant_type parameters.

From what I've read so far,
response_type is a query parameter on the /authorize endpoint and it's values can be either 'token' or 'code' which indicates that the authorization server will respond with an access token or an authorization code.

grant_type is a query parameter on the /token endpoint which indicates which grant type will the authorization server use to either generate a token or a authorization code. Grant types can be 'authorization_code', 'client_credentials', 'implicit' etc.

My question is, how will the authorization server behave if I pick the response_type as 'token' but the grant_type as 'authorization_code' ?
Since the authorization code grant is supposed to return a code and not a token, what is the server going to do in this scenario ?

Similarly, if I choose 'code' response type and 'implicit' grant type, what will be the behaviour ?

Answer (score 3):

### The *Authorization Code Flow*

(1) makes an authorization request to an authorization endpoint

(2) receives a short-lived authorization code

(3) makes a token request to a token endpoint with the authorization code

(4) gets an access token

### The *Implicit Flow*

(1) makes an authorization request to an authorization endpoint

(2) gets an access token directly from the authorization endpoint.

[image]

So the server will decide which flow to use, by inspecting the client's `response_type` in the GET request.

The *Implicit Flow* is handy, but it is a high risk due to a hacker easily getting an access token.
If the hacker changes his own redirect URL, he can get an access token. It is called *Man-in-the-middle attack*.

The *Authorization Code Flow* is more secure due to `code_challenge` and `code_verifier` doing a double check
between client and auth server. It is called *Proof Key for Code Exchange* (PKCE).
The server stores `code_challenge` and `code_challenge_method`, then, when asked for an `access_token`, verifies
`code_verifier` using `code_challenge` and `code_challenge_method`.

There exists also two other flows, *Resource Owner Password Credentials Flow* and *Client Credentials Flow*.

References:

[Diagrams And Movies Of All The OAuth 2.0 Flows](https://darutk.medium.com/diagrams-and-movies-of-all-the-oauth-2-0-flows-194f3c3ade85)

[Implicit Flow vs. Code Flow with PKCE](https://christianlydemann.com/implicit-flow-vs-code-flow-with-pkce/#:%7E:text=What%20are%20the%20differences%20between,on%20the%20redirect%2Ffront%20channel.)

Comment: That clears my doubt and a misconception I had that the token would be returned from the /token endpoint even in the Implicit flow which is not the case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, Can you have give me tums up by clicking up arrow in my answer, It makes me happy, Thank you.

Comment: I made a stackoverflow account specifically to ask this question. I dont have enough rep to vote yet.

Comment: Don't worry, you pressing give me a some points and make green check box even if  your reputation point less 15.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add a little here because I think the original poster was asking about a particular case and not the overall flows.
I think it's a good question that [the OAuth 2.0 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) doesn't explicitly address for this particular case.

> How will the authorization server behave if I pick the response_type
> as 'token' but the grant_type as 'authorization_code'?

There's not really a good reason for this to happen. If a client uses `response_type` with `token`, and the client is following OAuth 2.0, that means the client is sending a request to the `authorization` endpoint. The authorization server redirects the user agent to do some kind of authentication and ask for authorization from the resource owner. If everything is successful, the client gets an access token. There's no need to then make another call to the token endpoint where the `grant_type` would be needed. The authorization server should see this as an entirely different request. If the client first makes a request to the token endpoint with the `grant_type` of `authorization code` (which isn't following the OAuth 2.0 flow), the authorization server should respond with an error because the client wouldn't have an `authorization code` to use with the `code` parameter.

> grant_type
> REQUIRED.  Value MUST be set to "authorization_code".
>
> code
> REQUIRED.  The authorization code received from the
> authorization server.
> [4.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3)

The authz server doesn't have a memory of what the client "did previously". What I mean is that, as you mentioned, `response_type` and `grant_type` are parameters used at different endpoints. So requests making use of these are separate. `response_type` for when sending to the authz endpoint and `grant_type` is used when sending a request to the token endpoint.

Something that the authz server *does* need to handle, and can be an easy mistake by the client, is if it receives a `code` parameter **and** a `grant_type` parameter with something like `client_credentials` as its value at its token endpoint. I don't think this part is explicitly addressed in the spec because `code` is more like an extraneous parameter, but I believe it falls under the invalid request error because you could consider it an "unsupported parameter" given that the `grant_type` in the request was `client_credentials` and the client credentials grant type does not support that parameter:

> invalid_request:
> The request is missing a required parameter, includes an
> unsupported parameter value (other than grant type),
> repeats a parameter, includes multiple credentials,
> utilizes more than one mechanism for authenticating the
> client, or is otherwise malformed.
> [5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2)